# What is the Laurent series of $f(z)=1/z^2$

Tags: laurent-series

I have just looked at about 10 different Laurent series in the past days, but I cannot solve  $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$.

I attempt, $|z|>0$, with u=$z^2+1$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{z^2}=\frac{1}{z^2-1+1}=\frac{1}{u-1}=-\frac{1}{1-u}
\end{equation}

From here, assuming there exists **substitution method at all** for Laurent series, I get:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^nu^n=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^n(z^2+1)^n
\end{equation}

but this is not correct. The correct [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laurent%20series%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22LaurentSeries%22%2C%20%22taylorVariable%22%7D%20-%3E%22z%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22LaurentSeries%22%2C%20%22taylorFunction%22%7D%20-%3E%221%2F%20z%5E2%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22LaurentSeries%22%2C%20%22taylorPoint%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22) is :

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(1+n)(-1+z)^n
\end{equation}

It seems there is a rule of differentiation here, so I try this:

Put $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, and $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}$, we see that $g'(z)=-f(z)$

So

\begin{equation}
g(z)=\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{1-z-1}=-\frac{1}{z+1}\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{z+1}+1}=\frac{1}{z+1}\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{1}{z+1})}
\end{equation}

This gives

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{z+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\bigg(\frac{1}{z+1}\bigg)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(z+1)^n}
\end{equation}

Since $g'(z)=-f(z)$, then $-g'(z)=f(z)$, so I differentiate the series:

\begin{equation}
f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg((-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(z+1)^n}\bigg)' =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}(-n)(z+1)^{-n-1}
\end{equation}

But this is not entirely correct, though we are getting closer. What is the wrong in this last procedure here?

Comment: A function does have " a Laurent series," it has "a Laurent series in an annulus" that depends on the annulus. <> If you're expanding in the annulus $z \neq 0$ (i.e., $|z| > 0$), your work is done: The original representation of $f$ is _already_ a Laurent series in the punctured plane.

Comment: On what annulus are you finding your Laurent series? Because this matters. It seems as though you are trying to find your Laurent series with an annulus either centered around $z=-1$ or $z=0,$ but it is unclear, hence why i ask.

Comment: I try to expand this as a series on the region $|z|>0$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thanks for that. So I just expanded it as a geometric series instead, since the region is $|z|>0$. Note the correction. Still Wolfram gives another result.

Comment: The Laurent series of $1/z^2$ in the region $|z|>0$ is $1/z^2$, as Andrew pointed out in his comment

Comment: I thought n has to be infinite for that, but here it is only 2. So why does Mathematica develop it into a series similar to mine?

Comment: You can write it as $0/z +1/z^2 + 0/z^3 + 0/z^4 + \cdots$ if that makes you feel better.

Comment: :) that did it. But why is Mathematica developing it into a Power series?

Comment: How did you ask Mathematica to develop the Laurent series?

Comment: Search for "Laurent series calculator" at Wolframalpha, then insert the function $1/z^2$ with z as variable, expansion point $0$.

Comment: Did you mean Wolfram Alpha or Mathematica?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132966/discussion-between-viola-player-and-jjagmath).

Comment: Wolframalpha, not Mathematica. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments (except I lost a crucial *not* while typing), a function *doesn't* have " a Laurent series," it has "a Laurent series in an annulus" that depends on the annulus.

In more detail, since the comments have clarified the issue, the function $f(z) = 1/z^{2}$ is holomorphic on the punctured plane, and can be expanded as a Laurent series in every annulus not containing $0$. If $z_{0}$ denotes the center of the annulus, the Laurent series has the form
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{k} (z - z_{0})^{k}
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{-k}}{(z - z_{0})^{k}}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k} (z - z_{0})^{k}
$$
for some complex coefficients $(a_{k})_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}$. If this doubly-infinite series converges for some $z \neq z_{0}$, i.e., each of the series (negative degree and non-negative degree) converges for some $z \neq z_{0}$, then each series has positive radius. Consequently, there exist a real number $r$ and an extended real number $R$ with $0 \leq r < R \leq \infty$ such that the preceding series converges for $r < |z - z_{0}| < R$.

---

- Using the convention that terms with coefficient $0$ are omitted, $1/z^{2}$ is already a Laurent series of $f(z)$ about $z_{0} = 0$.
- The substitution $z^{2} = 1 - (1 - z^{2})$ does not yield a Laurent series about any $z_{0}$, because $1 - z^{2}$ has two distinct complex roots, so is not itself written in powers of $z - z_{0}$ regardless of $z_{0}$.
- Instead, to expand about $z_{0} = 1$, we need to use $z = 1 - (1 - z)$, so
  $$
  \frac{1}{z^{2}} = \frac{1}{[1 - (1 - z)]^{2}}.
  $$
  To expand the square, we can use the termwise-differentiation trick
  $$
  \frac{1}{(1 - u)^{2}}
  = \frac{d}{du} \biggl[\frac{1}{1 - u}\biggr]
  = \frac{d}{du} \biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} u^{k}\biggr]
  = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ku^{k-1}
  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k + 1) u^{k}
  $$
  with $u = 1 - z$, obtaining
  $$
  \frac{1}{z^{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k + 1) (1 - z)^{k}
  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} (k + 1) (z - 1)^{k}.
  $$
  This series converges where $|z - 1| < 1$, i.e., in the open disk of radius $1$ about $z_{0} = 1$.

Comment: is an annulus also $|z|>2$, or is it only squeezed between an infinite domain and a circle?

Comment: The set $2 < |z|$ is an annulus ($2 < |z| < \infty$) in the sense of Laurent series. :)

Comment: I see, so the annulus has to be defined with an upper and lower limit.  The region $|z|\geq 2$ is just a punctured infinite region?

Comment: In the same way we usually omit terms equal to $0$ in a series, an infinite upper bound on an inequality is often omitted without changing meaning (because $|z| < \infty$ is true for all complex $z$). The term _punctured disk_ usually refers to a disk without its center, i.e., points $z$ with $0 < |z - z_{0}| < R \leq \infty$. In the complex plane, the set $2 \leq |z|$ has no puncture; in the Riemann sphere, $\infty$ is a puncture. We could call this set a _closed annulus_, but to some that term signifies a compact set bounded by two concentric circles, like $2 \leq |z| \leq 5$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for all this written material!